# Global function is undefinded in scope of html loaded using jquery .load()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have html with :

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

in app.js I have function foo:

```
function foo() { console.log("foo") }
```

Then I have jquery and use it's method .load to load external html content:

```
$("#modal-wrapper").load("/modal_dialog_ajax", function () {
   // Some logic
});
```

Output of `/modal_dialog_ajax` looks like:

```
<div>Some markup</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 foo();
</script>
```

Javascript is executed fine but call of `foo()` is undefined in the scope of this html.

Why Js inside ajax loaded html content does not see global functions defined on the page?

Comment: What you've got should work provided that in `app.js` the `foo` function has been defined in the global scope

Answer (score 0):

Workarounded this using window global object:

```
function foo() { console.log("foo") }
window.foo = foo;
```

And then call it as

```
window.foo();
```

But not sure it is a good practice.